# Launch Ubuntu Backup in Terminal

Tags: software-recommendation, filesystem, backup

I've been searching for a tool (for Linux), that can "run" a backup of my server (filesystem) in my terminal. I've seen something like this a while ago, so I can't remember how this tools name was. Do you know a similar tool?

Comment: Depends upon how your backups are structured. If it's an uncompressed mirror of your regular filesystem, including your kernel, plain old KVM can run it with a minimum amount of hackery. If it's just data (compressed/encrypted), then you also need a cloud-image to provide the kernel and filesystem for KVM, and you mount/decrypt your backup like a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about `docker` or a virtual machine client like `vmware` or `virtualbox` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know, how I can use a existing filesystem with docker, if you even can...